# How to add custom setting preference in device's setting app in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Bluetooth based application and want to set some preferences in device's system setting app. The same way when user install a new input keyboard apk and its settings automatically appears in **Language and Input** option of device's setting app.

Similarly I want to add some preferences when user installs my app and Bluetooth settings of Settings app should get updated with my custom settings(like CheckBox preference etc.).

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own firmware, where you modify the Settings app [from its source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings) and include whatever you want. Then, you can distribute your own hardware that contains this firmware. This is how device manufacturers tailor the Settings app for their devices.

SDK applications cannot add system-wide preferences via the Settings app.

Comment: It means for Input method apps, the same procedure is followed?

Comment: @AndroDev: The Settings app already has the ability to allow the user to list available input method editors, choose one, and (at least on ICS) configure one. An arbitrary "Bluetooth based application" is not an input method editor; to configure that, create your own activity that is launched from the launcher.